# Iterate config array in html template via Angular directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got into AngularJS recently and trying to create a registration form where I would fill country list from my JavaScript config that is widely used elsewhere, thus I keep it as JS object.

I've been trying to use ng-repeat-start and *-end on my select input, but it fails.

The main question is, how do I load countries array and iterate it in my template?

**Edit: 30.11.2014 - Better examples**

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone">Country</label>
                <select-country ng-model="credentials.country"></select-country>
                <pre>{{credentials.country}}</pre>
            </div>
```

File:

> /public/directives/countrySelector.directive.js

Directive contents:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app', [])
.value('countries', [
    {name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'},
    {name: 'Åland Islands', code: 'AX'}
])
.directive('selectCountry', ['countries', function (countries) {
    function link (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.countries = countries;
    }

    return {
        template: '<select ng-options="country[1] as country[0] for country in countries"' +
        '        ng-model="credentials.country">' +
        '</select>',
        link: link,
        scope: {
            credentialsCountry: '='
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Are you looking for an answer that allows you to keep your `countries` array in a *separate* file of the project? A file that you can request via AJAX and load asynchronously?

Comment: Yes, as well. Aside from loading it properly into credentials scope via controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I don't think you need to make a new directive for this**.  There is already a built in select directive for angular, so you are making more work for yourself than necessary. So what you **could** do is inject that service into your controller for the page, then bind the service to the scope of the controller like you did for the directive.  It would end up looking something like:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.value('countries', [
    {name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'},
    {name: 'Åland Islands', code: 'AX'}
]);
```

and the you have a controller

```
app.controller('whateverTheControllerIs', ['countries', '$scope', function (countries, $scope) {
    $scope.countries = countries;
});
```

and then your scope is available to the template

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="phone">Country</label>
    <select ng-options="country.name for country in countries" ng-model="credentials.country"></select>
    <pre>{{credentials.country}}</pre>
</div>
```

**As a side note:** if you would like to find out about best practices for the latest Angular 1.* version.  Read everything Todd Motto says.

Comment: My main application module is called 'signals', I registered my value array to it using ``angular.module('signals', []).value('countries', [...]);``, to make it globally available for every controller, but it throws me an error: ``Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: countriesProvider <- countries`` whenever I try to use it in a controller and inject it as 'countries' service provider.

Comment: Fratyr, same way as in directive: http://plnkr.co/edit/OIGGitze5LLehDes2MQ8?p=preview

Comment: No, it never loads. Grunt does watches this file, but Angular never finds it. I've tried requiring it before the scope, and after. Placing under application module and the one that is trying to use it as well. No luck. Tried this: ``angular.module('users').value('Countries', [])`` Also tried ``angular.module('signals')`` // main module, and then requiring it in the controller. No luck :/ See my Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kNE6T0bf44bOUKFvkwOY

Answer (score 7):

just replace `country[0]` and `country[1]` with `country.code` and `country.name`

http://plnkr.co/edit/OIGGitze5LLehDes2MQ8?p=preview
or i missed something?

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to fix the display issue, now the problem is to register it properly! :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a good idea to create directives for things that could be commonly reused, like a country selector. You want to inject your `countries` into a directive where you can then iterate over it with `ng-options`. Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/zfkeLNQ0LHxR7FB0nM18?p=preview

```
.directive('selectCountry', ['countries', function (countries) {
  var directive = {
    template: '<select ng-options="country[1] as country[0] for country in countries"' +
              '        ng-model="ngModel">' +
              '</select>',
    link: link,
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    }
  };

  return directive;

  function link (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.countries = countries;
  }
}]);
```

Comment: The bad thing about this is that a MEAN stack example is using $scope.credentials object to send the registration form, so I cannot integrate my country and phone code selectors into credentials, since they are loaded in different times and failing to send select data.. :(

Comment: not completely clear on what you mean. If the form data is in an object `$scope.credentials` you can simply set `ng-model` for the country selector to `credentials.country` or similar. Do you have a code example?

Comment: You can see the new examples provided in original post. Thanks!

Comment: I feel like creating a directive for this is completely unnecessary.  You are literally just binding a service to a template (a very simple template at that).